# html template show me empty page

Tags: html, django, templates

when I try to run server th project th 1st pg which contains a list of names after I check one of them its suppose to show me details for this name but actually it does not work the pg was empty
can you please tell me what is my mistake?
thank u

project urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('new2/', include('new2.urls')),
]
```

app (new2) urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,re_path
from new2 import views

urlpatterns = (
    # path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
     re_path(r'(?P<task_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.details, name='details')
)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Task
from django.template import loader, RequestContext
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

def index(request):
    list_task = Task.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('new2/index.html')
    RequestContext = {
        'list_task': list_task
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(RequestContext,request))

def details(request, task_id):
    detail = Task.objects.get(pk=task_id)
    RequestContext = {
        'detail' : detail
    }
    return render(request,'new2/details.html',RequestContext)
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class Task(models.Model):
    def __str__ (self):
         return self.Name_task

    Name_task = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Age_task = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

details.html:

```
{{Task.Name_task}}</br>
{{Task.Age_task}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You passed the `Task` object as `detail` variable:

```
def details(request, task_id):
    detail = Task.objects.get(pk=task_id)
    context = {
        'detail' : detail
    }
    return render(request,'new2/details.html', context)
```

so that means you render it in the template as:

```
{{ detail.Name_task }}</br>
{{ detail.Age_task }}
```